# Replace option code with another code by using option index

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a dropdown list

```
<select name="answers[0][]">                            
   <option value="0" >Beredskap</option>                            
   <option value="1" >Förbundsledning</option>                          
   <option value="2" >Förbundsledning stab</option>
   <option value="3" >Ekonomiavdelningen</option>
</select>
```

What i am seeking for is to get the value `getElementsByTagName('select')[1]` and then replace it with

`<option value="1" disabled >Förbundsledning</option>`

the reason for it is that the list is auto generated so i need to modify the html output instead.

what i have sofar that does not work is :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
        .innerHTML.replace('<option value="1" disabled>apple</option>')
```

Answer (score 1):

The option with the value 1 happens to be at index 1 in your code, should that always be the case other answers than this one will apply.

In the case where you don't know the order of the generated options and thus don't know the index of the option you want to change, it depends on whether you want to change the text based on the value or the original text.

You could do this:

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
for(var e = 0; e < options.length; e++) {
    //change by text
    if (options[e].text == "Apple") {
        options[e].text = "Förbundsledning";
    }

    //change by value
    if (options[e].value == "1") {
        options[e].text = "Förbundsledning";    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery and selectors to find your list box $('#myListBox').val();

you can easily change the value by $('#myListBox').val("new value");

You can also easily iterate over the list of options and do whatever you wish.

```
$("#id option").each(function()
{
    // add $(this).val() to your list
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
sel.innerHTML = sel.innerHTML.replace('Förbundsledning', 'apple');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VxhvF/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[1].text="apple"`

`[1]` is index of your options item. 0 = Beredskap, 1 = Förbundsledning.

Answer (score 0):

use function ;

```
function select_text_replace(option_text, replace_text) {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(option_text, replace_text);
};


select_text_replace("Förbundsledning", "apple");
select_text_replace("Ekonomiavdelningen", "apple2");
```

see sample: http://jsfiddle.net/sm94N/